# Google Analytics: Why does  "/" appear in goal funnel visualization?

Tags: google-analytics

This is the goal funnel for checkout. Does anyone have any idea where the "/" is coming from? The cart page is at site: game on glove dot com (I don't want this stackoverflow page being indexed in google particularly well).

[image: google analytics goal funnel]

Go to the site, click on the order button, make your selection, and click the button to enter the cart (it resolves to /Cart and /Shop-Cart). I believe I used the regular expression matching to match "cart".

So why the "/" (I don't know what is causing the home page to reload when users are on the Cart page within a Colorbox lightbox where the only way back to home or "/" is to hit the exit button in the top right of the lightbox)?

Here's my one guess for the former question but it doesn't seem likely:
See the "check out with paypal" button? If you hovered over it, it does default to the home page which is what might be the "/"... but it really redirects the user to the paypal.com page so it shouldn't also load the home page.

Comment: Why is this tagged with jquery and colorbox? Is there a programming question here? Unless there is, this is completely off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I meant to say "why the '/'" rather than "what is the '/'". I also  added "I don't know what is causing the home page to reload when users are on the Cart page within a Colorbox (lightbox) since the only way back to the home page is to hit the exit button in the top right of the lightbox" above to clarify.

Comment: You're looking at this too narrowly. The user can always go back to your homepage, by refreshing the page, by typing the URL, by using a bookmark, by repeating a web search, etc. If they had previously viewed your cart, and have now viewed your homepage, that's an exit from your funnel to "/".

Comment: I wish I could accept that comment as my answer because that's what it is...I think. The reason I wasn't sure is because the exit button in the lightbox just executes javascript that closes the popup window rather than making an HTTP request.

Answer (score 4):

`/` is the root/index/home page of your site.

What that means is that 57 people that entered your cart went back to your homepage and didn't complete the funnel.

The list to the right of the red arrow are people leaving the 'Cart' step of your funnel without moving to the next step.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably have some steps in your funnel that either the regex isn't matching properly or that aren't registering properly (In other words people are completing your goal of login/register but none of them are completing it from the cart page this would suggest you're using the wrong URL to start the funnel or your missing a URL in between the cart and login).